# Cannot Get MYSQL DATEADD to Add The Year

Tags: mysql

This is really puzzling me as DATEADD should work and it isn't and wondered if anyone knew why.  Here is my statement:

```
$r = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT ID, DATEADD(year,1,BEGINDATE) AS NEXTYEAR FROM b_crm_deal");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r))
{
  print "".$row['NEXTYEAR']."<br />";
}
```

This doesn't return anything.  If I was to return the BEGINDATE it is:

```
2015-08-04 00:00:00
```

I basically want NEXTYEAR to return 2016-08-04 00:00:00.  I've tried the different combinations of year, yyyy, yy and nothing is returning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DATEADD` isn't a valid function in MySQL (it's MSSQL), use `date_add` instead:

```
DATE_ADD(BEGINDATE, interval 1 year) AS NEXTYEAR
```

See [the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

DATEADD looks wrong to me, see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_adddate

so try:

```
$r = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT ID, ADDDATE(BEGINDATE, INTERVAL 1 YEAR) AS NEXTYEAR FROM b_crm_deal");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r))
{
  print "".$row['NEXTYEAR']."<br />";
}
```